# Is it possible to combine public domain with other licenses

Tags: licensing, public-domain

I am a programmer and I am writing an application that depends on libraries with different licenses (for example, MIT, Apache or GPL), can I publish my application as a [Public Domain](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't including those libraries, then yes because it's entirely your own work.

If you are publishing those libraries, then no because their licenses will limit how you can do that. GPL's and MIT's main features are restricting how you can distribute software that includes the licensed code, and they don't allow the "do whatever you want" of public domain.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not a lawyer but this sounds questionable. Under US law, at least, if an application depends on a library, there's an argument to be made that it is a derivative work of that library. (That argument may be more or less likely to succeed depending on the details of the situation.) If so, then as far as I understand, it wouldn't be legal to create the application without satisfying the terms of the library's license, and those terms may forbid making the application public domain.

Comment: @David Z You mean the copyright of the API (function definitions) rather than the library itself? Didn't the famous Oracle vs Google case end up deciding that even implementing an API is fair use, and that surely also includes calling it.

Comment: No, I mean the library itself. An application which uses a library is (arguably) a derivative work of the library. This has nothing to do with the API which the library implements. (And as far as I know, Oracle v Google was about creating a separate implementation of an existing API, it had nothing to do with calling functions through the API and thus is not relevant here. I'm not an expert though.)

Comment: @DavidZ, Is it fair for the USA to call library '1' a derivative of library '2' if library '1' does not include library '2', but only accesses it dynamically, assuming that library '2' was pre-installed on a PC?

Comment: @DavidZ In the Oracle vs Google case, it would mean the 3rd party app developers calling those Oracle-owned API functions are breaking the law while Google implementing and providing them isn't. Maybe that's possible and some future case will decide that but it would be an utterly bizarre and inconsistent outcome.